# Issue with connecting django signals

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

I am trying to set up a History table that uses django signals in it in order to build a dashboard.

Inside my history models.py I have:

```
from django.dispatch import dispatcher
from django.db.models import signals
from project.models import Project

...

dispatcher.connect(update_dash, signal=signals.post_save, sender=Project)
```

However, .connect keeps coming up as a unresolved reference.

Oh by the way, I've used this site for a reference to start using signals. [MercuryTide](http://www.mercurytide.co.uk/news/article/django-signals/)

Has anyone had this issue before or am I missing something?

Thanks,

Steve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That article is *ancient* as far as Django is concerned. Consult the [latest documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/) to see how we do things today.

Comment: Are there any up to date tutorials or examples?

Comment: No I have read through what you have shown me, which I appreciate, I just also like to see examples, or tutorials too.  Sorry thats how I learn.